# Scrape wikipedia table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I would like to scrape the table titled "List of chemical elements" from the wikipedia link below and display it using pandas

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements

I am new to beautifulsoup and this is currently what i have.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r
import pandas as pd

response = r.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements')

wiki_text = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki_text, 'html.parser')

table_soup = soup.find_all('table')
```

Comment: What is your problem? You are on your way to get there! print out table_soup and find out the gap between what you have and what you want. You can get it! Ask more questions when you have problem in converting this HTML table to pandas DataFrame. Hint: get data element one by one, row by row. Slow, but works in the very beginning.

Comment: Hi! I am having trouble to find the id or class of the table. I have tried searching from print and inspect element as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the `table` with `beautifulsoup` in different ways:

1. By its "title":

   ```
   soup.select_one('table:-soup-contains("List of chemical elements")')
   ```
2. By order in tree (it is the first one):

   ```
   soup.select_one('table')
   soup.select('table')[0]
   ```
3. By its `class` (there is no id in your case):

   ```
   soup.select_one('table.wikitable')
   ```

#### Or simply with `pandas`

```
pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements')[0]
```

*To get the expected result, try it yourself and if you have difficulties, ask a new question.